# How to add a not-nullable UDT column to an existing table?

Tags: sql-server

I have a user defined data type that has a default constraint on it. I want to add a new not-nullable column to an existing table using this UDT. However, if I add it like this:

```
ALTER TABLE MyTable
ADD MyUdtNotNullableColumn UDT_MyDataType NOT NULL
```

I get the standard error that I can't add a not-nullable column if it doesn't have a default value.

If I try to add the column like this:

```
ALTER TABLE MyTable
ADD MyUdtNotNullableColumn UDT_MyDataType NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N'
```

I get an error that the column already has a default specified. What is the proper way of doing this?

Comment: Take the default off your UDT.

Comment: You mean temporarily?

Comment: No. You have conflicting stuff happening. Your UDT has a default already so trying to add a default to the table is a bit of a challenge. How would sql server know which default you actually want.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood what you meant by "Take the default off your UDT."

I'm able to do what I want by actually unbinding the default from the UDT, applying a generic default to the new column, then rebinding the original default. How else are you supposed to use default bindings on UDT's?

Comment: Can you post your UDT? That way we aren't guessing and speculating anymore.

Comment: If you need a UDT with a default you should let it be the default. Changing it for every table kind of defeats the purpose doesn't it?

Comment: IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[DF_FLAG]') AND OBJECTPROPERTY(object_id, N'IsDefault') = 1)
EXEC dbo.sp_executesql N'CREATE DEFAULT [dbo].[DF_FLAG] 
AS
''N'';


'

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.types st JOIN sys.schemas ss ON st.schema_id = ss.schema_id WHERE st.name = N'UDT_FLAG' AND ss.name = N'dbo')
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[UDT_FLAG] FROM [varchar](1) NOT NULL

Comment: It is better to post code in the question as the comments decimate any kind of formatting. But I don't see a default on your UDT. Not really sure why you have that dynamic sql in there either.